# .tblk file doesn't work

Tags: vpn

I am trying to set up Tunnelblick on my computer. (I have Mac OS X 10.9 on a 13" Macbook Pro with 4GB of RAM.)

1. I started by downloading Tunnelblick.
2. Next, Tunnelblick automatically gave me the following file (called "config.ovpn"):
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYI7qMrKuDYV1BGUm4xQkZkbGs/edit?usp=sharing
3. After that, I followed the instructions by creating a folder called "Empty Tunnelblick VPN configuration" and copying "config.ovpn" to the folder. I then renamed the folder "Empty Tunnelblick VPN configuration.tblk".
4. I followed another set of instructions and then double-clicked the file "Empty Tunnelblick VPN configuration.tblk". However, I got the following error message:[image]

What did I do wrong? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Tunnelblick questions are better asked on the Tunnelblick Discussion Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tunnelblick-discuss).

The problem is that line 88 of your configuration file contains a reference to a file named "ca.crt" and that file is not in the "Empty Tunnelblick VPN Configuration.tblk". All files referenced in a configuration file must be placed in the .tblk.

(The reason the paths are so weird is because Tunnelblick is referencing a temporary copy of the .tblk that you are trying to install.)

Comment: So what EXACTLY should I do?

Comment: @TechMaster100: I had the same problem.  Ends up the `ca.crt` file had a lock on it.  Remove the lock and you should be fine.